# Android layout file is not updating

Tags: android, layout

I'm developing an android app, I'm testing with samsung galaxy tab, for any reason my xxx_layout.xml is not working, it remains in its first version, if I modify it none of this changes are viewed, I make all the process to generate an signed apk, clear any data in the tablet before install but this problem still appearing.

Please any sugestion or solution is welcome, thanks

Greetings

Answer (score 3):

Do you have another definition that is ovrriding this one?

Files in `res/layout/` are "defaults" or fallback versions that are used when no better one is found. Now on a tablet,with a hdpi or xlarge screen, layouts in `res/layout-hdpi` or `res/layout-xlarge` are taken before the ones in `res/layout`.

Comment: Hi Heiko, thanks for your reply, there is only one version of res/layout (there is no res/layout-hdpi or res/layout-xlarge) and inside only one file, so it shouldn't take any previous version of the file and this is just in this tablet, in emulator is working fine 
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

can you make sure that this layout file is actually used.

also check if you have any errors in the layout file.

Comment: Hi clamp, I'm sure, the file doesn't have errors and also I get the file that is inside *.apk and I decompiled it and is the same file that I edited
Greetings

Comment: hi, by "actually used" i meant that your code actually inflates the layout to some view.